# Calling 7zip from a SAS macro

Tags: sas, 7zip

SAS is my primary software for this project. I am using SAS to call 7zip. Both SAS and 7zip are 64 bit versions. The objective is to read compressed US NOAA weather station data for 4 years -- about 4,000 stations, so approx. 16,000 files.

Each file contains multiple,  variable length, undelimited records with each record containing date, time, and weather information for a given station (e.g., temperature, visibility, precipitation, and so on). This problem is not about reading the *records*. It's about reading the *files*.

These files are not stored using an extension of any type, e.g., there is no *.txt, *.dat, *.gz, *.tar. Nothing defining a file type is used in their naming. I have checked this by turning the ‘File Name Extension’ option on and off in Windows File Explorer. File extensions appear for other information but not for the NOAA files. Each file name has 3 fields. The first two fields define a unique NOAA weather station (USAF and WBAN respectively) and the last field is the year. Here are some representative file names:

702120-26646-2011

702120-26646-2012

702120-26646-2013

etc.

Since the files are compressed, I am using 7zip to uncompress them with a macro call from SAS. Here is the SAS macro syntax for these calls:

> %do year=2011 %to 2014;
>
> filename in pipe "c:/7-zip/7z.exe x
>
> ""C:\data\stuff\weather\data\extracted.zip\extracted\&&usaf-&&wban-&&year\""
>   -so" lrecl=3000;
>
> run;
>
> %end;

And here is resolved code for 1 file:

> MLOGIC(LOOPS):  %DO loop beginning; index variable YEAR; start value
>   is 2011; stop value is 2014; by value is 1.
>
> SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable USAF resolves to 702120
>
> SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable WBAN resolves to 26646
>
> SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable YEAR resolves to 2011
>
> MPRINT(LOOPS):   filename in pipe "c:/7-zip/7z.exe x
>   ""C:\data\stuff\weather\data\extracted.zip\extracted\702120-26646-2011\""
>   -so" lrecl=3000;
>
> MPRINT(LOOPS):   run;
>
> NOTE: The infile IN is:
>
> Unnamed Pipe Access Device,
>
> PROCESS=c:/7-zip/7z.exe x
>
> "C:\data\stuff\weather\data\extracted.zip\extracted\702120-26646-2011\" -so,
>   RECFM=V,LRECL=3000
>
> Stderr output:
>
> ERROR: The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> C:\data\stuff\weather\data\extracted.zip\extracted\702120-26646-2011
>
> System ERROR:
>
> The system cannot find the path specified.

Clearly there are no errors in syntax but SAS cannot find the file.

*The thing that is confusing me is that the file exists or resides in the folder exactly as specified by the resolved path.*

Is there a mistake in the 7zup call such that it can’t find the file? For instance should a 7zip option other than “-so” be used?

What else could be going wrong here? Any suggestions are most welcome!

Comment: Did you try running those commands directly from the prompt to see if it provided any hints as to the issue?

Comment: Also, while SAS may not care whether you use `/` or `\ ` the operating system will definitely care.  Not sure how the pipe command resolves them but you may just want to change all path references to use `\ ` to be sure.

Comment: @RobertPenridge Many thanks for your comments. *Directly from the prompt*? As written the program is custom and inot reliant on either SAS Interactive or EG. In other words I specifically click the *run* button to invoke the code. Given that I don't see how I could run it *from the prompt*. Also in calling 7zip SAS doesn't care which way the */* goes.

Comment: Assuming Windows 10... Click on the `Start` button in windows.  Type in `cmd` and select the "Command Prompt" option.  From the prompt that appears, try and run the command you are trying to run within SAS.  If it works in the prompt, it should work in SAS.  If it doesn't work, it should provide you additional feedback.  It won't work from the prompt unless you correct the / chars to \ so I'd definitely recommend doing that to start with.

Comment: @RobertPenridge  Interesting suggestion. The first attempt returned 'System ERROR: The directory name is invalid. c:\7-zip\7z.exe x ""C:\data\stuff\weather\data\extracted.zip\extracted\"" -so "     While the second attempt *c:\7-zip\7z.exe x ""C:\data\stuff\weather\data\extracted.zip\extracted\423630-99999-2013\"" -so "* returned this:  *Command Line Error:  Empty file path.*  To me this suggests that 7zip thinks the NOAA file name is another folder?

Comment: Yeah basically all we're trying to do is remove SAS from the equation and get the command working from the operating system first.  Once that works, it's simply a case of substituting it into your SAS code.  Try removing one set of double quotes, `c:\7-zip\7z.exe x "C:\data\stuff\weather\data\extracted.zip\extracted\" -so`

Comment: If that still doesn't work, try renaming one of the files and see if your command works if the file has a suitable file extension. It would be quite simple to rename all the files in this way using a `ren` command if that proves to be a viable workaround.

Comment: @RobertPenridge and User667489  Many thanks for these helpful suggestions. After extracting all of the files (size went from 17g to 130g), and focusing the 7zip call on just one of them (c:\7-zip\7z.exe x "C:\data\stuff\weather\data\extracted\423630-99999-2013\" -so) I got a totally *new* error, a popup window stating:  **Access denied. This app can't run on your PC. To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher.**  This tells me that this cmd command is correct but there is a new problem wrt the Windows 10 OS.

Comment: @User667489  Thanks for your helpful comment. See above...

Comment: Ha! The joke's on me. After decompressing the files I don't need 7zip anymore. Thanks to both of you for your wise advice.

Comment: I use this to zip and it could easily be modified to unzip. It explicitly lists the steps out so that it's easy to debug errors: https://gist.github.com/statgeek/9602105

Answer (score 1):

SAS now supports reading ZIP files directly.  Try something like this:

```
filename in zip "C:\data\stuff\weather\data\extracted.zip"
   member="&usaf.-&wban.-&year." 
   lrecl=3000
;
```

Comment: That's a helpful suggestion for future work. Thank you.